# how to get image from database using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I try to get image on my jsp, and it doesn't work.. JSP didnt show image. Using SpringMVC, Spring Data (JpaRepository), jdbc. PostgreSQL and HSQL(doesnt work on both)

My code:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Images")
public class Image {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String name;

@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private byte[] body;
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/imageDisplay", method =     RequestMethod.GET)
public void showImage(@RequestParam("id") Integer id,  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        Image image = bookService.getImage(id);
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif");
        response.getOutputStream().write(image.getBody());
        response.getOutputStream().close();


}
```

Service:

```
public Image getImage(int id) {
    return imageRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

JSP:

```
<img src="/image/imageDisplay?id=${book.image.id}" class="media-object pull-left">
```

I will be very grateful for help! Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: JSP doesnt show image
Виктор, подозреваю что Вы понимаете по-русски, в общем на странице не отображает картинку. ID в контроллер "входит" корректное. Я подозреваю, что возможно проблема с ImageRepository и  getImage, возможно надо подругому извлекать blob ?